# Is it possible to add some arrows to ms2gallery and use it as carousel?

Tags: modx, modx-revolution, modx-resources

I have project on modx and there is used `ms2gallery` to show images. And customer want to add some arrows(prev, next) to use this `ms2gallery` as carousel or slider. Is it possible to build-in this functional into `ms2gallery`? If not could you advice something to solve this task?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pdoPage snippet for just this purpose. Here's the example form the [ms2Gallery documentation](https://modstore.pro/packages/photos-and-files/ms2gallery):

```
[[!pdoPage?
    &element=`ms2GalleryResources`
    &parents=`0`
    &tpl=`@INLINE
    <p>
        <a href="[[+uri]]">[[+pagetitle]]</a>
        <a href="[[+120x90.original]]"><img src="[[+120x90]]" title="[[+120x90.name]]" /></a>
    </p>
    `
    &typeOfJoin=`inner`
    &includeThumbs=`120x90`
    &includeOriginal=`1`
]]
[[!+page.nav]]
```

You will need to add some extra properties to the snippet call to get more than one result. All the available options and several examples are documented on the [pdoPage readme](http://docs.modx.pro/components/pdotools/snippets/pdopage).